# By trying replicate my database with sync gateway, the documents aren't syncronized because sync gateway return 401 Login required

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, couchbase-lite, couchbase-sync-gateway

I'm using couchbase lite cordova plugin v1.3.1 from https://github.com/couchbaselabs/Couchbase-Lite-PhoneGap-Plugin.git

Trying to syncronize my databse with sync, the log sync shows that request {server_ip:4984}/{mysync-gateway}/_local/... responses an 401 login required in couchbase lite cordova, and method replicate appear not accept Authorization header, same setting this header the replicate method throws an error.

Comment: I put in replication url as http://user:pass@{ip}:{port}/{sync} and the replication functioned

Comment: You can configure this in Sync Gateway so you don't need to authenticate if you want.  Look at the examples around enabling Guest access.